# dart - Write body of HttpClientReques failing?

Tags: dart, httprequest

I was trying to send data to a local server using HttpClient. However, the data is never added to the request, I'm using this code:

```dart
      new HttpClient().put('127.0.0.1', 4040, '/employees/1').then((request) {
        request.cookies.add(new Cookie('DARTSESSID',sessionId)..path = '/');
        request.headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "");
        request.headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/json");
        request.write('{"id": 1,  "name": "luis"}');

        print(request.contentLength);
        return request.close();
      }).then(expectAsync((HttpClientResponse response) {
        expect(response.statusCode, 200);
        UTF8.decodeStream(response).then(expectAsync((body) {
          expect(body, equals('"employee: 1"'));
        }));
      }));
```

but that always prints that the request.contentLenght is -1. I saw those links before without luck:

https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=13293

[dart - HttpClientRequest failing on adding data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776746/dart-httpclientrequest-failing-on-adding-data)

https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=10026

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ContentLength` of `-1` does not mean that there is no data, it means that the length of the content is unknown and that a streaming content mode is used - for HTTP 1.1, this will usually mean `Chunked` `ContentEncoding`.

I've tried to insert your code in a setup including a server, but without the unittest stuff:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  HttpServer.bind('127.0.0.1', 4040).then((server) {
    server.listen((request) {
      UTF8.decodeStream(request).then((body) {
        print(body);
        request.response.close();
      });
    });
    new HttpClient().put('127.0.0.1', 4040, '/employees/1').then((request) {
      request.cookies.add(new Cookie('DARTSESSID', "1")..path = '/');
      request.headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "");
      request.headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/json");
      request.write('{"id": 1,  "name": "luis"}');

      print(request.contentLength);
      return request.close();
    }).then((HttpClientResponse response) {
      UTF8.decodeStream(response).then((body) {
        print(body);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

When I run the code, I get

```dart
-1
{"id": 1,  "name": "luis"}
```

as expected. Perhaps the problem you are having are on the server?

Comment: the problem was caused since I was asking for the contentLength on the server also. It appears that the contentLength value wasn't setted before sending the data to the server. To solve the problem, I decoded the stream and check if the body is empty instead checking the content length. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Writing to the request is an asynchronous operation. Just because the contentLength says that it still is -1 doesn't mean that the data isn't added to the request before sending it to the server.

Also: the content-length is not supposed to update whenever you add new data. It is the value that is sent to the server. -1 means that you don't know the size yet.
I'm not sure, if the library automatically updates it, if it knows the size, but it doesn't need to.

Comment: Yes, but still I cannot get data on the server. It always send empty  request body. What else can I do to write data to the request body?